# What's different in Journey for PS4?

Tags: version-differences, journey

[Journey](http://thatgamecompany.com/games/journey/) is now available for PS4. **Is there anything different and/or new in this version of the game** compared to the original game, released on the PS3?

Answer (score 5):

There are no differences between both games as far as content and gameplay is involved.<sup>**[[1]](http://www.gamesradar.com/journey-very-different-ps4-despite-being-exactly-same-game/) [[2]](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/3e5uhy/differences_between_journey_ps3_and_ps4/)**</sup>

There is, however, the improved graphics that comes with the improved hardware of the PS4 compared to the PS3. Most notably, 720p →  1080p and 60 FPS, as well as significantly less lags and slowdowns, even during the more demanding scenes in the game.

The PS4 version also has the same trophies as the PS3 one, though they are not shared. In other words: even if you earned all trophies on the PS3, you can earn them again on the PS4.